# Instagram API - how to get a list of recently tagged media

Tags: jquery, instagram-api

Hi community im really new on this, im trying to search a post on instagram (this app will used in my web application), im already search on all answers on this few days, and try most of all code that community provide. And, its a dead end for me. 
This is my complete code

**1.home.php**

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="w">
    <section id="sform">
    <input type="text" id="s" name="q" class="sfield" placeholder="Enter a search tag..." autocomplete="off">
    </section>
    <section id="photos"></section>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**2.ajax.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var sfield = $("#s");
    var container = $("#photos");
    var timer;

    function instaSearch() {
    $(sfield).addClass("loading");
    $(container).empty();
    var q = $(sfield).val();

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'instasearch.php',
    data: "q="+q,
    success: function(data){
    $(sfield).removeClass("loading");
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    var ncode = '<div><h1>'+data[i].name+'</h1><p>'+data[i].mediacount+'</p></div>';
    $(container).append(ncode);
    });
    },
    error: function(xhr, type, exception) { 
    $(sfield).removeClass("loading");
    $(container).html("Error: " + type); 
    }
    });
    }

    $(sfield).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == '32' || e.keyCode == '188' || e.keyCode == '189' || e.keyCode == '13' || e.keyCode == '190' || e.keyCode == '219' || e.keyCode == '221' || e.keyCode == '191' || e.keyCode == '220') {
    e.preventDefault();
    } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
    instaSearch();
    }, 900);   
    }
    });
    });
```

**3.instasearch.php**

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $client = "xxxxx";
    $access_token = "xxxxxx";
    $query = $_POST['q'];

    $api = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q='.$query.'&access_token='.$access_token.'';

    function get_curl($url) {
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
    } else {
    return file_get_contents($url);
    }
    }

    $response = get_curl($api);

    $datang = array();
    if($response){
    foreach(json_decode($response)->data as $item){     
    $mediacount = $item->media_count;
    $name = $item->name;

    $datang[] = array(        
    "mediacount" => htmlspecialchars($mediacount),
    "name" => htmlspecialchars($name),
    );
    }
    } 

    print_r(str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($datang)));
    die();
```

the output was okay, for now..
next step, i want to change this

```
    $api = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q='.$query.'&access_token='.$access_token.'';
```

into this

```
    $api = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$query.'/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token."";
```

and it return an error (copy paste from my web browser)

```
    {
    "pagination": {
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
    },
    "meta": {
    "code": 200
    },
    "data": []
    }
```

please community, how can i solve this problem? Anyone, please?
I want to make output (JSON at least) like mentioned here https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

on GET /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent..

Thank you community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved !

[Instagram API search by tag doesn't return anything](http://progrnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/instagram-api-search-by-tag-doesnt.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in js

```
var sfield = $("#s");
var container = $("#photos");
```

You stored jquery element in a variable and later on you are calling jquery on a jquery element. Replace $(sfield) with sfield. Also do that for container

Comment: thank you by the way, but its not solved this problem.

Comment: any idea about pagination on instagram API ?

Comment: I've never used instagram api. Have you checked the value that has been sent by ajax? Maybe you are sending empty string every time